# moodle email confirmation not working

Tags: php, email, authentication, configuration, moodle

I'm configuring Moodle for a school project and there is a problem in email confirmation process.
following are my configurations:

**outgoing mail confirmations**

```
SMTP hosts: stmp.gmail.com:465
STMP security:TLS
STMP Auth Type:LOGIN
SMTP username:****@gmail.com [*admin e-mail*]
SMTP password:****
SMTP session limit:1
```

**no-reply domain**

```
no-reply address:***@gmail.com [*admin e-mail*]
Allowed email domains :
```

**Email display settings**

```
Character set : UTF-8
Allow user to select character set :no
Allow attachments: yes
Email via information: always
```

when user signed up; admin gets a notification that new user required access but the **new user wont get any confirmation email**.[before and after confirmation from site admin]

no email can be found in spam or inbox.

please help!!!

Comment: "SMTP hosts: stmp.gmail.com:465"
Surely that should be smtp.gmail.com:465
Or is that just a typo in your post?

Comment: thanks for showing my mistake. but even though I tried that it still doesn't work. new user doesn't get any confirmation email.

Answer (score 0):

For the outgoing mail configuration you should just leave all the settings blank or revert them to their defaults. Unless you have a dedicated SMTP server (i.e. one that is hosted within your organisation and is specifically configured to relay outgoing mail from your Moodle server) then you should just let Moodle use PHP's own mail libraries to send mail.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for advising. i tried that way too. but it still didn't work.no confirmation mail is going to the new user.

Comment: Do you have cron running?

Comment: Do you have debugging turned up to developer level?

Comment: @Sakuni, you need to make sure that cron is running scheduled tasks and that you have debugging enabled and turned up to developer level. Then you need to enrol a new user and you should either see debug messages on the page, or you'll find them in your server error log. That will help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Tony tank you for your help. but still it does not work.